# Android Layout: How to get a particular ancestor of a view

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I have a layout similar to the capture. The green rectangles are placed in horizontal scrollers and when the user touches one, another activity is launched. The blue rectangles are other layers, like the horizontal scrollers.

My problem: when the user touches a green rectangle, I need to know in which RED rectangle the touched green rectangle is placed in.

Is there any easy way to get a particular ancestor of a view? I would like to be able to add and remove more "blue rectangles", so I don't want something like `view.getParent().getParent().getParent()` .

Thanks!

Comment: Add the Objects you need in Tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways,

Simpler one:

Set the red ones as tag to all the child it contains, now when a child receive Touch you can easily figure out who is the parent among red, by getTag method.

Little Complex but cooler:

a. Maintain a list of all the red view
b. Implement on Touch on green one
c. Get the x,y when you receive touch
d. Once you receive Touch, loop through list of red view, getting Hit Rect for each red view, once you get the hit rect, just check if it contains ur received x,y. Once you found match return. Wollah you have your parent view.

Hope it help.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll stick to the simpler one.